# Modal window where I can click on the underlying Parent tab items?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

Within my LWC component, I was able to implement a [Modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals) window within my console application and it's working great -  Opens, closes, no problem.

Now, I would like to perform some input operations (entering data on the input form) on the Parent tab while this Modal window is open. But, looks like, I cannot click on any of the underlying tab. Is there a way or workaround I should do to perform what I need? Pointing to any resources would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modals are supposed to take focus and not allow you to work on background elements when it is open.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/#Accessibility

> Modals, by definition, trap focus. This means that if a user presses
> Tab or  Shift+Tab while their keyboard focus is in the modal, their
> focus should stay in and cycle through the modal’s content. Focus
> shouldn’t return to the underlying page until the user presses the Esc
> key, presses an explicit “Cancel” or “Close” button in the modal, or
> performs another action that closes the modal.

Not sure what your requirement is but if you want to perform background actions - try using lightning-tabset components ?